# RSocket and Spring not handle multiple requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java

I play with RSocket together with Spring boot. I want to make simple request-response example. As example I took code from this link:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rsocket#request-response

Source code:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5-webflux/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/rsocket

When I run example code without change I get error during request with Exception. This error is not point of this question, but I just want to show changes comapre to original source by baeldung.

> [reactor-tcp-nio-1]
> org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: [5927a44d-9]  500 Server
> Error for HTTP GET "/current/pko"
> io.rsocket.exceptions.ApplicationErrorException: N**o handler for
> destination ''    at**
> io.rsocket.exceptions.Exceptions.from(Exceptions.java:76)     Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has
> been observed at the following site(s):   |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler
> com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.client.MarketDataRestController#current(String)
> [DispatcherHandler]   |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/current/pko"
> [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace:        at
> io.rsocket.exceptions.Exceptions.from(Exceptions.java:76)         at
> io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleFrame(RSocketRequester.java:706)
> at
> io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleIncomingFrames(RSocketRequester.java:640)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:554)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:630)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:670)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:205)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:260)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:366)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)         at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

So I change client code from

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RSocket rSocket() {
        return RSocketFactory.connect()
                             .mimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                             .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
                             .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(7000))
                             .start()
                             .block();
    }

    @Bean
    RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies) {
        return RSocketRequester.wrap(rSocket(), MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON, rSocketStrategies);
    }
}
```

to

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {
    

    @Bean
    RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies) {
        return RSocketRequester.builder()
                .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies)
                .connectTcp("localhost", 7000)
                .block();
    }
}
```

This small change help, an exception does not occur. Other issue that is point of that question iis that requests from client(requester) are processed one by one by server(responder). I create SOAPUI REST project and run GET request in 2 thread. It look like server use single thread. This is not what I expect to achieve.

To make it easy I will show whole solution.

#### Server :

Simple controller

```
@Controller
public class MarketDataRSocketController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MarketDataRSocketController.class);

    private final MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;

    public MarketDataRSocketController(MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository) {
        this.marketDataRepository = marketDataRepository;
    }

    @MessageMapping("currentMarketData")
    public Mono<MarketData> currentMarketData(MarketDataRequest marketDataRequest) {
        logger.info("Getting data for: "+marketDataRequest);
        Mono<MarketData> result = marketDataRepository.getOne(marketDataRequest.getStock());
        logger.info("Controller thread move forward: "+marketDataRequest);
        return result;
    }

    @MessageExceptionHandler
    public Mono<MarketData> handleException(Exception e) {
        return Mono.just(MarketData.fromException(e));
    }
}
```

In repository I add `Thread.sleep(10000);` just to simulate long running operation.

```
@Component
public class MarketDataRepository {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MarketDataRSocketController.class);
    private static final int BOUND = 100;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Mono<MarketData> getOne(String stock) {
        //return return Mono.just(getMarketDataResponse(stock)); original code from baeldung.
        return Mono.just(stock).map(s -> getMarketDataResponse(s));
    }

    private MarketData getMarketDataResponse(String stock) {
        logger.info("Repository thread go speel ZzzZZ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("Repository thread move forward");
        return new MarketData(stock, random.nextInt(BOUND));
    }
}
```

#### Client

Simple client configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {


    @Bean
    RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies) {
        return RSocketRequester.builder()
                .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies)
                .connectTcp("localhost", 7000)
                .block();
    }
}
```

And simple REST Controller that I use in SOAP UI

```
@RestController
public class MarketDataRestController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MarketDataRestController.class);

    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final RSocketRequester rSocketRequester;

    public MarketDataRestController(RSocketRequester rSocketRequester) {
        this.rSocketRequester = rSocketRequester;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/current/{stock}")
    public Publisher<MarketData> current(@PathVariable("stock") String stock) {
        logger.info("Get REST call for stock : "+stock);
        return rSocketRequester.route("currentMarketData")
                               .data(new MarketDataRequest(stock))
                               .retrieveMono(MarketData.class);
    }
}
```

When i RUN server and client I get incomprehensible behavior to me. By SOAP UI I make single request in 2 threads.

In client log I get:

> 2021-09-01 11:30:14,614 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-2] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.client.MarketDataRestController: Get REST call for stock : pko 
> 2021-09-01 11:30:14,691 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.client.MarketDataRestController: Get REST call for stock : pko

In server I get logs like:

Log from first shot:

> // **get data from client** 
> 2021-09-01 11:30:14,843 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRSocketController: Getting data for: MarketDataRequest(stock=pko)
> // **Log that Contoller thread go forward after call repository** 
> 2021-09-01 11:30:14,844 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRSocketController: Controller thread move forward: MarketDataRequest(stock=pko)
> // **Log that repository sleep thread** 
> 2021-09-01 11:30:14,862 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRepository: Repository thread go speel ZzzZZ
> // **Repository finish work** 
> 2021-09-01 11:30:24,863 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRepository: Repository thread move forward

Server is procesing only single call and just wait when repository finish job. Then process next request in similar way:

> 2021-09-01 11:30:24,874 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRSocketController: Getting data for: MarketDataRequest(stock=pko)
> 2021-09-01 11:30:24,874 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRSocketController: Controller thread move forward: MarketDataRequest(stock=pko)
> 2021-09-01 11:30:24,874 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRepository: Repository thread go speel ZzzZZ
> 2021-09-01 11:30:34,876 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-3] com.baeldung.spring.rsocket.server.MarketDataRepository: Repository thread move forward

I don't understand why the server is processing calls one by one. Maybe there is some problem in code or maybe I'm not understand something right.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Reactor, by default, everything is running on the main thread. Calling  `Thread.sleep` the main thread is blocking and the application freezes. if you would like to simulate a long-running operation you could use the [delayElements](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-) operator:

```
.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Note: [Reactor BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) detects and reports such blocking calls.